# USB Camera with Rasperry Pi: Sending raw data from dev/video0 to PC through tcp/udp

Tags: camera, wireless, video

I want to send the raw USB data to my laptop to process it and then send it back (image processing). Is there any way I can just send the data through tcp/udp without raspi doing all the hard work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just issue a simple read() on /dev/video*. You have two options:

1. Use OpenCV to open the camera, something like this:

   ```
   // includes, setup code, etc.
   Mat frame;
   VideoCapture cam(1);
   for (;;) {
     cam1.grab();
     cam1.retrieve(frame);
     if (frame.empty() {
       continue;
     }
     // Serialize frame and send it over a network connection.
   }
   ```
2. Use the `usbip` package to relay the raw usb data over to your other machine; this assumes that his other machine can also run the corresponding side of the usbip driver. This package is seriously buggy, I have never had good luck with it.

How you send data back to the Pi is up to you, of course!

Comment: I've tried installing OpenCV but it fails on RasPi(Something to do with ARM vs x86 architecture) . All the solutions are related to compiling OpenCV on the pi. Is there any other way?

Comment: I've used OpenCV on the Pi in the distant past. Why is compiling it a problem?